# Problemas Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

Hola amigos al intentar correr mi app me muestra el siguiente error:

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

The dependencies in your gemfile changed

You have added to the Gemfile:
* mysql2 (~> 0.5.1)
* bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* bcrypt (~> 3.1.12)
* mysql2
```

pero lo raro es que al parecer no se ha modificado ninguna gema y ya intente borrar el gemfile.lock y dando bundle install de nuevo pero sigue el error, muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega tu Gemfile a la pregunta. De todas formas lo que te dice en lo que pusiste es que corras `bundle install` en otra parte con el Gemfile, y el lock que te genere, agrégalo a tu proyecto actual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue borrar el cache generado en rails `tmp/cache` por windows que causaba conflicto y no dejaba ejecutar `bundle install`.